# How do I derive the transformation law of a Weyl spinor under a Lorentz transformation?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, group-representations, spinors, lorentz-symmetry

Let $\xi$ be a [spinor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinor).
If $(\theta ,\phi)$ are the parameters of a rotation and pure [Lorentz transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation), then how can we prove that the transformation rule for $\xi$ can be written as
$$\xi ~\rightarrow~ \exp\left(\ i \frac{\bf{\sigma}}{2}\cdot \theta +\frac{\bf{\sigma}}{2} \cdot \phi\right) \xi,$$
where $\sigma$ are the [Pauli matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices)?

Comment: Are you comfortable with pure rotations, i.e. do you still have trouble if I set $\phi=0$?

Comment: It is not clear what the question is asking for. Do you mean to ask why a spinor transforms that way?

Comment: @unlimited-dreamer, I suppose you've offered a bounty because you're not satisfied with the current answer. You've got to explain what you're looking for. Else, this question could be downvoted for being poorly framed.

Comment: my question isn't fuzzy i think. I just wanted to get the equation$\xi ~\rightarrow~ \exp\left(\ i \frac{\bf{\sigma}}{2}\cdot \theta +\frac{\bf{\sigma}}{2} \cdot \phi\right) \xi~?$. 
any help would be approciated. Thanx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write an infinitesimal transformation, with generator $J$, as
$$
R(\delta\theta) = 1 + iJ\delta\theta
$$
A finite transformation is a succession of $N\to\infty$ infinitesimal transformations, 
$$
R(\theta) = (1 + iJ\theta/N)^N = e^{iJ\theta} 
$$

The rotations $O(3)$ are isomorphic to $SU(2)$, with generators $J = \sigma/2$. The Lorentz transformations are similar to rotations, but with hyperbolic functions rather than trigonometric functions; $\sinh=\gamma\beta$ and $\cosh\phi=\gamma$, because the boosts satisfy $\gamma^2-\gamma^2\beta^2=1$. You can find that the Lorentz generators are $K = \pm i\sigma/2$.

Putting this together, for the negative solution, you find
$$
R(\theta, \phi) =\exp\left(\ i \frac{\bf{\sigma}}{2}\cdot \theta +\frac{\bf{\sigma}}{2} \cdot \phi\right)
$$
This is the *right-handed* $(1/2,0)$ solution. (The alternative positive solution is the *left-handed* $(0,1/2)$ solution.)

Answer (score 4):

You are giving the lorentz transformation of a left-handed Weyl spinor. A very detailed derivation of those formulas is given in [1] for example.

In short the appearence of the two pauli matrices stems from the fact that the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so(3,1)}$ of the lorentz group is the same as $\mathfrak{su(2)\times\mathfrak{su(2)}}$. So the rotations are generated by $\mathfrak{su(2)}$ as well as the boost (however note the extra factor $i$).

[1] Maggiore, Michele *A Modern Introduction to Quantum Field Theory*, 2005